# Query sub-documents with an offset in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following data:

```
{
  _id: '123',
  name: 'Foobar',
  friends: [
    { name: 'a' },
    { name: 'b' },
    { name: 'c' },
    { name: 'd' },
    { name: 'e' }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to query MongoDB to return a list of `friends` with an offset - e.g. skip the first two friends in the array ('a' and 'b') and return only 'c', 'd' and 'e'?

I've tried to use `$slice`, but it seem to require a "limit" as well, e.g.

```
db.users.findOne({ _id: '123' }, { friends: { $slice: [2,-1] } })
```

This will not work, since the "limit" (`-1` in the above example) needs to be a positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't terribly elegant, but just provide a limit value large enough to effectively not be a limit:

```
db.users.findOne({ _id: '123' }, { friends: { $slice: [2,1000000000] } })
```